# Backup Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: server, backup, remastersys

I downloaded remastersys and it created an iso but I cannot get it to install my system on another hard drive.

When it boots it shows the loading bar, which from my experience appears when starting ubuntu desktop, and then boots to a distorted command line, and not with the correct user@host.

So I ask is there a way to create a distributable backup of all my settings on my working server and install it on several computers?

Can someone provide me with a source.list url that will enable me to backup my server rather than desktop which I think the remastersys version I downloaded is doing.

Current one I'm currently using is the deb file from:
http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository/karmic/

thanks

Comment: This has a reasonable answer; I advise against closing it as abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you appear to have downloaded a deb file for Karmic and your question is about Oneric. According to the Remastersys website you should be using version 3.0.0-1

> For Lucid and Newer - version 3.0.0-1
>   Remastersys for Lucid and newer 
>   deb http://www.remastersys.com/repository/lucid/

I recommend you have a read through the [documentation on the site for Ubuntu](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html), especially the notes about the **dist** and the **backup** options. If you follow the steps and recommendations correctly it should work ok.